# Prove that f is riemann integrable iff $\exists A \in \mathbb{R} \epsilon - \delta$ s.t. $|S(p,f) -A|< \epsilon$ for every $S(p,f), |P| < \delta$

Tags: real-analysis

**Edit:** I greatly appreciate everyone's help and I hope this question helps someone else in the future. It seems that my professor mostly just wanted us to evaluate the Riemann sum and compare it to the value of A.

I need help figuring out how to write this proof. The question is to evaluate the function $f(x)=x^3-x^2+3x+2$ using the following:
Let a function $f:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be bounded. Prove that $f \in \scr{R}[a,b]$ iff $\exists A \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\forall \epsilon>0, \exists \delta>0$ such that $|S(p,f)-A|<\epsilon$ for all $S(p,f), where |P|<\delta$ and $A=\int^b_af$

So far I know $A=\frac{34}3$, my professor gave us the partition $Pn={0,\frac2n,\frac4n, . . ., 2-\frac2n,2}$, so $|Pn|=\frac2n$ and $c_k=x_k$ with $c_k$ as the right end point of the interval $[x_{k-1},x_k]$. And I know one of the things I need to do is find $S(p,f)$ and fill in the gaps from that to getting $\frac{34}3$

Proof: Let $f(x)=x^3-x^2+3x+2$ and let $f:[0,2] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be bounded. Since $f(x)$ is a polynomial, it is continuous on $[0,2]$. And since it's continuous, theorem 6.2.4 says $f\in\scr{R}[0,2]$.

I believe this is where I need to prove that there must exist an A, but other than simply proving that A is $\frac{34}3$ by taking the integral, I'm not sure how to go about this. Or at least, if I need to use the partition given, I don't quite understand that application. I think if I can get this direction down, I should be able to get the other just fine.

Comment: Are you trying to integrate the function $x^3 - x^2 + 3x + 2$ using the criterion you stated, or are you trying to prove the criterion for integrability that you stated: "Let a function $f \colon [a, b] \to \mathbb{R}$ be bounded. ..."?

Comment: We were asked to evaluate $\int^2_0 x^3-x^2+3x-2$ using the criterion stated.

Answer (score 1):

You showed that $f(x) = x^3 - x^2 + 3x + 2$ is Riemann integrable on $[a, b]$. From the theorem you stated, it easily follows that if $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[a, b]$ and $P_n$ are tagged partitions of $[a, b]$ with $|P_n| \to 0$, then the Riemann sums associated to the tagged partitions $P_n$ converge to $\int_{a}^{b}f(x)\,dx$. So you can take the limit of the Riemann sums on your equally spaced partitions as $n \to \infty$ to compute $\int_{a}^{b}f(x)\,dx$.